# Combine p-values of several independent samples for combined hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, combining-p-values

I have a dataframe with 4 columns, corresponding to different emotions extracted with ML methods from one video. The dataframe describes one person, rows represent moments in time. Now I'm trying to mark dataframe as insignificant, if the detected emotions are almost-constant.

So, my H0 is: "any of the emotions is non-stationary".

Now I perform Augmented Dickey-Fuler test (with null hypothesis "the series is non-stationary") on every series and obtain p-values (code in python given below for reference together with a df sample and major stats). I end up having 4 p-values.

How should I combine those? I can formulate H0 as "any of the emotions is non-stationary with alpha=0.01" and reject it if all p-values obtained are below 0.01, but this sounds not statistically correct, because from the global point of view I'm checking the whole dataset and not separate series. With my original H0 formulation I have to combine 4 p-values into one somehow. I suppose Fisher's method does not apply here, because it was developed for dependent cases with the same null hypothesis, and my case is different.

Here's the dataframe sample and some code (please ignore "neutral" column because it's linearly dependent on 4 others - they add up to 1):

```py
>>> from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(...).dropna()  # Insignificant df
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv(...).dropna()  # Significant df
>>> df.head()
    Unnamed: 0  time     angry    scared     happy   neutral       sad
8            8   1.6  0.046867  0.030736  0.042334  0.814897  0.065166
9            9   1.8  0.051908  0.038864  0.045297  0.791667  0.072264
10          10   2.0  0.042280  0.033831  0.055860  0.797632  0.070397
11          11   2.2  0.064768  0.017584  0.040667  0.841843  0.035137
12          12   2.4  0.070928  0.022191  0.033639  0.825483  0.047759
>>> df[cols].describe()
            angry      scared       happy         sad
count  272.000000  272.000000  272.000000  272.000000
mean     0.047902    0.026313    0.053351    0.058907
std      0.014715    0.009156    0.022048    0.017035
min      0.017400    0.010842    0.011263    0.024328
25%      0.037608    0.019508    0.039247    0.047019
50%      0.046432    0.024267    0.049815    0.055466
75%      0.055815    0.031104    0.064834    0.068593
max      0.142180    0.055817    0.222235    0.139777
>>> df2.head()
    Unnamed: 0  time     angry    scared     happy   neutral       sad
8            8   1.6  0.009712  0.004793  0.202277  0.758015  0.025203
9            9   1.8  0.008974  0.005125  0.112469  0.841718  0.031714
10          10   2.0  0.007013  0.004551  0.221301  0.738514  0.028622
11          11   2.2  0.005347  0.002529  0.224950  0.746677  0.020497
12          12   2.4  0.004089  0.002009  0.315020  0.665884  0.012998
>>> df2[cols].describe()
            angry      scared       happy         sad
count  272.000000  272.000000  272.000000  272.000000
mean     0.006801    0.003985    0.403518    0.025887
std      0.004960    0.003326    0.340374    0.024425
min      0.000014    0.000007    0.014501    0.000036
25%      0.003299    0.001642    0.097946    0.010492
50%      0.005878    0.003536    0.288607    0.021846
75%      0.009877    0.005776    0.671007    0.033472
max      0.024246    0.021502    0.998112    0.180877
>>> for col in cols: print(adfuller(df[col])[1])
... 
1.7074987958656052e-16
2.0059524498747396e-07
9.910010274093592e-09
2.6496740053033137e-19
>>> for col in cols: print(adfuller(df2[col])[1])
... 
0.08205085843597149
0.02944711896782458
0.319362154099021
0.009455210475492137
```

In the code above I want to recognize `df` as insignificant (all p-values are below 0.01) and `df2` as significant (some p-values are over 0.01). What is the right thing to do? `all(p_values < 0.01)` seems not fair and Fisher's method - inapplicable. I don't need python code, only mathematical explanation or link to good source for applicable algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to CV. "Non-stationary" and "almost constant" would appear to be slightly different things.  A series can be non-stationary yet have constant mean while a wildly varying series around a constant mean can be stationary.  This suggests that investing more initial thought into what you really need to test and how to quantify that might pay off in producing a more definite and relevant question to answer.

Comment: @whuber Sorry for not using the terminology properly, I need to check exactly for stationary series, not for constant mean. I want to test that all series are non-stationary, and need a way to combine results of several tests.

Comment: If you find even a single non-stationary  series, then by the rules of logic you must reject the null hypothesis that all of them are stationary.  It is nonsensical to formulate a null that supposes "any are non-stationary," because that is untestable.  If this sounds strange, then check out our posts on hypothesis testing and TOST.